# Join two tables and get only most recent entry from second table

Tags: sql, firebird

I need to make this firebird query, please help

I have 2 tables:

TABLE 1: CLIENT

```
ID, NAME, TEL, ADRESS, EMAIL
```

TABLE 2: CRM_INTERACTIONS

```
ID, CLIENT_ID, DATE, INTERACTION_TYPE
```

I need to retrieve all fields of the client table plus 2 columns of the table 2 which are: **The last interaction_type for that client plus the date** so the view looks like this:

```
ID, NAME, TEL, ADRESS, EMAIL, DATE_OF_LAST_INTERACTION, INTERACTION_TYPE

1, JOHN, 555555,1TH ST, John@gmail.com, 01/10/2016, phone call
```

Answer (score 1):

I think firebird 3+ has `row_number()`, so you can do:

```
select c.*, ci.*
from client c left join
     (select ci.*,
             row_number() over (partition by client_id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from crm_interactions ci
     ) ci
     on c.id = ci.client_id and seqnum = 1;
```

In earlier versions, you would do this using traditional SQL.  Here is one way:

```
select c.*, ci.*
from client c left join
     crm_interactions ci
     on c.id = ci.client_id left join
     (select ci.client_id, max(date) as maxdate
      from crm_interactions ci
      group by ci.client_id
     ) cci
     on ci.client_id = cci.client_id and ci.date = cci.maxdate;
```

Comment: I tested it and it almost solve the problema, just one issue: leaving it this way it will only show the client with interactions but not every client has values in the ci table. I also replaced both joins using left join but then it duplicates client records. Any idea?